# Spaces are gone in HTML after upgrading to vue-cli 3

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I was using vue cli 2 without any custom configuration. Now I upgraded to cli3 and i noticed in the processed HTML it removes ALL whitespace. 
e.g. if my original html is this:

```
<div class="link">
    <i class="fa fa-lg" :class="item.icon"/>
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

the old (cli 2 + webpack) would convert it into this:

```
<div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-calendar"/> <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">CALENDAR</span></div>
```

whereas the new one does this:

```
<div class="link"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-calendar"/><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">CALENDAR</span></div>
```

note the space is gone before `<span class...` which causes this:

[image: with space]

to become this:

[image: without space]

My vue.config.js is pretty basic:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

I know I can just add `&nbsp;` or make other changes to html itself, but the app is quite large and looking for all these places will take days.

Does anybody know the options I need to ensure it optimizes html the same way it did with the old cli+webpack combo?

Comment: There's [an open issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1020) in vue-cli, referring to [this PR](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/7598) - but it's still not merged. You can either merge it manually or use `preserveWhitespace: true`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @raina77ow pointed to the links to the issue, `preserveWhitespace`  defaults to `false` in vue-loader options.

You can configure the [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/)'s template compiler option `preserveWhitespace` to `true` using the [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) file

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule("vue")
      .use("vue-loader")
      .loader("vue-loader")
      .tap(options => {
        // modify the options...
        options.compilerOptions.preserveWhitespace = true;
        return options;
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on Vue 3. any other option?

Answer (score 9):

The @VamsiKrishna answer works fine, but `preserveWhitespace` is deprecated since vue-template-compiler 2.6, you may use new option `whitespace` instead:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule("vue")
      .use("vue-loader")
      .loader("vue-loader")
      .tap(options => {
        // modify the options...
        options.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve';
        return options;
      });
  }
};
```

You may check other options and valid values [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/packages/vue-template-compiler#options).

#### Vue 3

On Vue 3, You may use application config, here is the [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions-whitespace):

```js
const app = createApp({});

app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve';
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on Vue 3. any other option?

Comment: @antoni It's not implemented yet, check this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5909#issuecomment-700425509

Comment: haha thanks, I am actually the author of that issue.

Comment: @antoni hahaha :))))

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work on Vue 2 but not since Vue 3.

### It is now possible in vue-cli since Vue version 3.1.0.

But with a different setup: it's only possible to use the `compilerOptions` when you use the "full" build that includes both the compiler and the runtime so it supports compiling templates on the fly. e.g. `vue.global.js` https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#from-cdn-or-without-a-bundler

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#compileroptions

[image]

You can add this globally where you define your app (usually main.js):
`app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve'`

or in a component (https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#compileroptions):

```js
export default {
  compilerOptions: {
    whitespace: 'preserve'
  }
}
```

### And in Vite (later than Vue version 3.0.6):

in `vite.config.js`

```js
  plugins: [
    createVuePlugin({
      vueTemplateOptions: {
        compilerOptions: {
          whitespace: 'preserve'
        }
      }
    })
  ], // https://vitejs.dev/config/
```